# Concurrent acces to a static member in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I've a class that contains a static collection to store the logged-in users in an ASP.NET MVC application. I just want to know about the below code is thread-safe or not. Do I need to lock the code whenever I add or remove item to the onlineUsers collection.

```
public class OnlineUsers
{
    private static List<string> onlineUsers = new List<string>();
    public static EventHandler<string> OnUserAdded;
    public static EventHandler<string> OnUserRemoved;

    private OnlineUsers()
    {
    }

    static OnlineUsers()
    {
    }

    public static int NoOfOnlineUsers
    {
        get
        {
            return onlineUsers.Count;
        }
    }

    public static List<string> GetUsers()
    {
        return onlineUsers;
    }

    public static void AddUser(string userName)
    {
        if (!onlineUsers.Contains(userName))
        {
            onlineUsers.Add(userName);

            if (OnUserAdded != null)
                OnUserAdded(null, userName);
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveUser(string userName)
    {
        if (onlineUsers.Contains(userName))
        {
            onlineUsers.Remove(userName);

            if (OnUserRemoved != null)
                OnUserRemoved(null, userName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw - none of that code is async... question title is confusing

Comment: I would argue that those members shouldn't be static. What was your reasoning behind it?

Comment: @Marc, you are correct. Asynchronous has nothing to do with this. I got little messed up when I typed the question :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is absolutely not thread safe. Any time 2 threads are doing something (very common in a web application), chaos is possible - exceptions, or silent data loss.

Yes you need some kind of synchronization such as `lock`; and `static` is usually a very bad idea for data storage, IMO (unless treated very carefully and limited to things like configuration data).

Also - `static` events are notorious for a good way to keep object graphs alive unexpectedly. Treat those with caution too; if you subscribe once only, fine - but don't subscribe etc per request.

Also - it isn't just locking the operations, since this line:

```
return onlineUsers;
```

returns your list, now unprotected. ***all*** access to an item must be synchronized. Personally I'd return a *copy*, i.e.

```
lock(syncObj) {
    return onlineUsers.ToArray();
}
```

Finally, returning a `.Count` from such can be confusing - as it is not guaranteed to still be `Count` at any point. It is informational *at that point in time only*.

Comment: I know you get this a lot, but great answer!

Comment: Your point about "Count" being unreliable is perhaps the most important and frequently misunderstood aspect of multithreaded programming of mutable types. Normally the way you reason about code in single threaded life is that memory is stable unless you do work to mutate it. In multithreaded code, the opposite is true: you have to assume that everything is constantly changing unless you are doing work to keep it stable. When you observe the size of a collection *you are observing the size it was in the past*. It might have mutated a million times immediatly after you counted it.

Comment: @Eric the one I think is subtle is accidentally exposing the list, now completely unprotected, naked, and vulnerable to assault.

Comment: @Marc I agree with John you gave a great answer. I don't understand why static events are not good. Can you point out some links or references to know more.

Comment: @Mark treated carefully they are fine; but if you subscribe from a *transient* object (that lives a very short time), but ***forget to unsubscribe***, you will keep that object alive forever. It will cause memory growth over time as you repeat that process, and will make invoking it progressively slower and slower.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to lock the `onlineUsers` to make that code threadsafe.

A few notes:

- Using a `HashSet<string>` instead of the `List<string>` may be a good idea, since it is much more efficient for operations like this (`Contains` and `Remove` especially). This does not change anything on the locking requirements though.
- You can declare a class as "static" if it has only static members.

Comment: He could make it a static class, but IMO these members should not be static in the first place.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, that's right of course. But since the Op is obviously a newbie I didn't want to write a "you're doing it all wrong" kind of answer. Suitable techniques to replace the static class here may be a bit complicated for the Op to follow.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Can you please tell me why those members should not be marked static. I just want to correct my mistakes.

Comment: @Lucero Is a single lock object is enough to lock the collection in all the places?

Comment: @Mark, with the exception of the `GetUsers` class a single lock is good enough. As written by others, you should not return the original instance in `GetUsers`, otherwise you'll not be able to control what is done on that reference.

Comment: @Lucerco Thanks for your reply. I totally agree with you I should return a copy of the list as mentioned by @Marc.

Comment: @Mark Global mutable state is generally problematic. Especially when writing tests. The clean solution is using dependency injection to get a single instance of your class. The common compromise for people who don't use DI is the singleton, where you have a single static property `Instance` pointing to the instance of your class. http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @Mark and in your case the choice is even more dubious. It's very easy to imagine having multiple instances of your class inside a single process/AppDomain. For example if you want to run multiple independent chat systems at the same time.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Thanks for your replies. I understand the problems in the design. Instead of having the static collection I should make the class as Singleton.

Comment: I'd argue that in this case it should just be a normal class, not even a singleton. Just create a single instance. And if you must make it a singleton limit how often you access the `Instance` static field as much as possible. I prefer having a non static field in my controller that points to your instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do need to lock your code.

```
 object padlock = new object
 public bool Contains(T item)
 {
    lock (padlock)
    {
        return items.Contains(item);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You need to lock the collection before you read or write to the collection, since multiple users are potentially being added from different threadpool workers.  You should probably also do it on the count as well, though if you're not concerned with 100% accuracy that may not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

As per Lucero's answer, you need to lock onlineUsers. Also be careful what will clients of your class do with the onlineUsers returned from GetUsers(). I suggest you change your interface - for example use `IEnumerable<string> GetUsers()` and make sure the lock is used in its implementation. Something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetUsers() {
    lock (...) {
        foreach (var element in onlineUsers)
            yield return element;
        // We need foreach, just "return onlineUsers" would release the lock too early!
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation can expose you to deadlocks if users try to call some other method of OnlineUsers that uses lock, while still iterating over the result of GetUsers().

Comment: That will cause blocking, not typically deadlocks (unless there is a second resource in play) - but personally I would avoid this scenario - returning a copy of the data is usually very cheap and avoids the huge risks associated with this approach. In particular, I can foresee something like `foreach(var user user in GetUsers()) DoSomethingExpensive(user)` which would block all other access for an unpredictable (but too long) amount of time. Best avoided, IMO.

Comment: @Marc Agreed, but that depends on concrete usage scenario. If there are few users and the list is frequently modified, the copy is is probably better. If there are many users and the list is fairly static (AND there is no DoSomethingExpensive() from your example), my solution is probably better. As always "it depends"TM ;)

Comment: Re the deleted comment re deadlock; no that wouldn't deadlock - locks are re-entrant. And yes, you do need a lock on .Count

Comment: @Marc If the thread iterating through GetUsers() tries to wait on another thread that then tries to acquire a lock on the list, this would cause a deadlock.

Comment: waiting on the thread - I'd call that a resource :) but yes, *that* would deadlock. So if that is a real risk - don't expose data like this :)

Comment: I'm returning the list just for display so I think a copy will do.

Answer (score 1):

That code it is not thread-safe per se.

I will not make any suggestions relative to your "design", since you didn't ask any. I'll *assume* you found good reasons for those static members and exposing your list's contents as you did.

However, if you want to make your code thread-safe, you should basically use a lock object to lock on, and wrap the contents of your methods with a lock statement:

```
    private readonly object syncObject = new object();

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        lock (this.syncObject)
        {
            // Work with your list here
        }
    }
```

Beware that those events being raised have the potential to hold the lock for an extended period of time, depending on what the delegates do.
You could omit the lock from the NoOfOnlineUsers property while declaring your list as volatile. However, if you want the Count value to persist for as long as you are using it at a certain moment, use a lock there, as well.

As others suggested here, exposing your list directly, even with a lock, will still pose a "threat" on it's contents. I would go with returning a copy (and that should fit most purposes) as Mark Gravell advised.

Now, since you said you are using this in an ASP.NET environment, it is worth saying that all local and member variables, as well as their member variables, if any, are thread safe.